# MacOS Form Validation Rule on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, macos, forms, laravel-8

I'm trying to Validate my contact form in Laravel. I'm trying to show error input on the form. On Windows I'm able to show what error is appearing, for example like 'name' field is required. But in MacOS, it seems as if the Validation is bypassed.
Here is my validate function in ContactController

```
public function process(Request $request): RedirectResponse
      {
        $request -> validate([
           ['name' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required|max:50',
            'message' => 'required|max:255']
                         );
        
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Email sent successfully');            
      }
```

I've tried to use Validator::, and also set MAC Address configured on my network. I've tried this.

```
public function process(Request $request): RedirectResponse
      {
        $request -> Validator::validate([
            'mac' => '2c:f0:ee:2f:b9:5e'],
            ['mac' => 'mac_address'],
           ['name' => 'required|string|max:50|min:5',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required|max:50',
            'message' => 'required|max:255']
                         );
        
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Email sent successfully');            
      }
```

But it seems I don't see any display of error that's actually been displayed [on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pqxi.png).
What am I missing? Or I'm actually using wrong syntax?

n.b. I already added Use Illuminate/Validation/Validator; in my controller.

edit:
This is form in my view if this could help.

```
<form method ="post" action="{{ route('validate') }}" role="form" class="php-email-form">
              @csrf
              @if ($errors -> any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
              @endif
              <div class="row">
                <h3>Send Me an Email</h3>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                  @error('name')
                      <div class="error_msg">
                          <p class="text_xsm fc_red">
                              {{ $message }}
                          </p>
                      </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <label for="name">Your Email</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                  @error('email')
                      <div class="error_msg">
                          <p class="text_xsm fc_red">
                              {{ $message }}
                          </p>
                      </div>
                  @enderror
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"placeholder ="Subject" name="subject" id="subject" value="{{ old('subject') }}">
                @error('subject')
                      <div class="error_msg">
                          <p class="text_xsm fc_red">
                              {{ $message }}
                          </p>
                      </div>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" name="message" id="message" rows="10" value="{{ old('message') }}"></textarea>
                @error('message')
                      <div class="error_msg">
                          <p class="text_xsm fc_red">
                              {{ $message }}
                          </p>
                      </div>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="my-3">
                <div class="loading">Loading</div>
                <div class="sent-message">
                  
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" value="process">Send Message</button></div>
            </form>
```

Comment: What's the expected result? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are stuck?

Comment: How are you trying to get the error in the frontend? Are you getting sent back without success (meaning validation failure)?

Comment: @NicoHaase my expected result would be '@error' method catching what the error is, and then displaying it with little red word under the input form. When I tried it in Windows without inputting anything and just clicked the Submit button, I can see little red word that said 'The name field is required', 'The email field is required', and other error.

As I already said on the post, I've tried to use Validator:: when I'm browsing on how to solve this, but seems like it's still not working. Maybe I'm missing something else which I don't know what.

Comment: @Yinci It seems so, I put {{ old('name') }} value inside every input form so that I can retain wrongly inputted form, but it seems my form on MacOS doesn't retain anything and that validation is bypassed and just redirected back.

Comment: I've never had issues with multiple different Macs, so I can't imagine it's MacOS related. What browser are you using? Are there by chance things happening in the console? What happens when you `dd($errors)` after submitting? (Edit the blade view after page load).

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @Yinci I'm running the code with replit, in Safari. I didn't notice any issue in the console. I don't really know if I'm actually using dd($errors) correctly, but here is what returned. Lost all css/js element while only having pure html inside, with this line added.
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#269 ▼ // resources/views/web/contact.blade.php
  #bags: []
}

Comment: A `dd` is server side, so yes, css and JS won't be processed. Anyhow, it seems you don't have any errors. I have no experience with Replit, but perhaps that's where it's going wrong. I would suggest Laravel Sail personally. The validation code looks fine, so if you have the correct inputs, then you should get errors.

Comment: And just to add, this code looks very dated; use of [`FormRequest` classes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#form-request-validation) for validation has been the standard for 5 years now. Old method of in-controller validation is still supported and documented of course, but it's much less flexible.